# How to strip reliably most comments in Matlab code?

Tags: text-processing, sed, python, perl, matlab

I want to remove comments reliably without removing newlines (`\n`) and any piece of essential Matlab code by Unix commands, not by extensions/gadgets/... existing for the target etc [here](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4645---matlab-comment-stripping-toolbox). 
Test cases

1. The symbol `%` elsewhere in the code, not indicating comment etc in `sprintf('Masi % score')`.
2. Ignore tricky ones etc `sprintf('Masi % score'); % do not need to remove this comment because tricky`
3. ...

I think SED can work well. Some attempts

- Attempt 1 faulty because removes newlines and fails test case 1

  ```
  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/3350246/54964
  sed -e 's/%.*$//' -e '/^$/d' inputFile.m

  ## Output 
  function blalala(var2);
  var=1;      
  hello=2; 
  assert(indexPositionEnd >= indexPositionStart, 'indexEnd bigger/equal than indexStart');
  index=index+1
  pause(1); 
  sprintf('Masi 
  end
  ```
- Attempt 2 faulty because includes only first line in output

  ```
  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/54964
  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/%.*$/ /g' inputFile.m

  ## Output  
  function blalala(var2);
  ```

Example `inputFile.m` as data file

```
function blalala(var2);
%% synapse
% describe here pla la
%
var=1;      
% 
hello=2; 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      Statistics and Monitoring
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

assert(indexPositionEnd >= indexPositionStart, 'indexEnd bigger/equal than indexStart');

index=index+1

%% Situation monitoring at the end
pause(1); % waitforbuttonpress pause is not sufficient

% http://stackoverflow.com/a/111322....

sprintf('Masi % score').
sprintf('Masi % score'); % do not need to remove this comment because tricky

end
```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Tools: SED, Python, Perl, ...

Comment: Maybe you could use matlab code? http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/262710

Comment: This one is tricky: `sprintf('Masi % score'); % Remove this comment`. It should be something like `sed -e "s/\(^.*'.*%.*'.*\)%.*$/\1/"`

Comment: I am not trying to argue against your use case, but why do you want to strip out the comments?  Also, consider stack overflow (healthy stack there under 'matlab' tag).

Comment: @Xalorous I have bugs in my sources codes. I need to make much test cases all the time to maintain the integrity. I use binary search strategy i.e. I delete some parts of codes and try to find the reason why the bug(s) came in the first place. In complex systems, it takes a lot of time. Comments 2-3x the length of my codes often. To have a different view of codes can help.

Comment: Thank you.  What about search and replace in vim?  Or sed with regex to select any line that starts with a comment character.  Both cases would probably take the whole line, including the newline, but maybe that would be acceptable?  Also, are there any graphical IDE's that can hide comments? [SO about folding comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296924/hiding-comments-in-matlabs-editor).  Also, it mentions notepad++ and visual studio.  Yuck windows, I know, but there should be a graphical editor to let you do the same in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*%[^'\'']*$//'
```

This removes line-ending comments, only if the comment text does not contain a single quote. It leaves the line's newline.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243401).  Set the color of comments the same as the background.